# How can I create a link to a prefilled cart and coupon?

Tags: commerce

We could use some help with the following use case.

1. We are selling online magazine subscriptions via the shop. Magazine subscriptions are implemented using commerce license.
2. We also offer subscription packs to enable customers to purchase a pack of 5 subscriptions for organizations. The customer gets a unique coupon that can used 5 times, enabling 5 organization members to purchase an individual license with 100% reduction.

In order to streamline the process and make it more intuitive and user friendly we would like to send the customer an email containing a link to the checkout page of a cart containing the license and the unique coupon filled out. This would enable the organization members that are entitled to the license to easily obtain the license if the customer then forwards that mail to them.

Do you have any idea on how this can be achieved?

We are using Drupal 9 and Commerce Core 2.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.